# How to compile a java project to obtain a .jar file

Tags: java

hello someone could suggest me how to compile the java project that I attach to generate the sri.jar file that appears in the Readme file

//Project java to compile
https://github.com/joselo/sri

//command line where the sri.jar that I want to generate appears

```
 java -jar sri.jar /path/sample/certificate.p12 cErTiFicAtEPaSsWoRd /path/sample/unsignedFile.xml /path/sample outputFile.xml
```

Comment: I thought that to create a jar file took two steps:  javac to create class files and jar to build the jar.

Comment: Could you help me with the full command since I am not proficient in java?

Comment: The task will be to use some tools provided in the JDK on your PC,  There might not be any need to know the java language.  Do you have a JDK installed?

Comment: I have a debian distro, and is this version ok https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Comment: With an IDE or Ant or Maven. There is really no excuse for using a command line any time in the last 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

To create a jar file first thing that needs to be done is to compile the project using javac

`javac -cp ./sri-master/lib/*: ./sri-master/src/sri/*.java -d ./out/`

and then run the below to create the jar

`jar cvfm xyz.jar ./sri-master/manifest.mf -C ./out/ .`

Comment: Hello Kunal Vohra, thax for your response, I need help with one more thing, when i run the line it gives the following error: there is no main manifest attribute in xyz.jar

Comment: please check you are setting the right path for the manifest file